Apply Labels Based On Thresholds Defined In One Dataframe To Another Dataframe
I have two Pandas dataframes, and I'm looking to find a faster way to apply the labels defined in the first dataframe to the rows in the second:

df1: The first dataframe has thresholds for a number of categories along with associated labels




id
Category A
Category B
Lower Bound
Upper Bound
Label




1
Red
One
1
3
X


2
Yellow
Two
3
5
Y


3
Blue
Three
5
7
Z




df2: The second has the raw data values that need to be labeled according to the thresholds in the first table. If Value in df2 is between Upper Bound and Lower Bound in df1, then apply the appropriate label to that row (assuming match on Cat A and B).




id
Category A
Category B
Value




1
Red
One
2


2
Yellow
Two
4


3
Blue
Three
6



After the labels are applied from the first to the second, the resulting dataframe df2 should look like:



id
Category A
Category B
Value
Label




1
Red
One
2
X


2
Yellow
Two
4
Y


3
Blue
Three
6
Z



I'm currently able to do this using df.apply and iterrows like follows:
def applyLabels(row, dfLabel,_):
    for index, rowLabel in dfLabel.iterrows():
        if row[Category A] == rowLabel[Category A] & row[Value] between Upper and Lower Bound...
            return dfLabel.at[index, 'Label']

df2['Label'] = df2.apply(applyLabels, args=(df2,_), axis=1)

This takes forever (I'm working w/ ~10 million rows) - is there a faster way to achieve this result without exporting this whole thing to SQL?
*edit - changed the bound labels as one commenter noted they were backwards.
I've tried a merge as recommended here, but it doesn't seem to be faster, not sure if I'm missing something?*

Did you switch the column names for the lower and upper bounds? Or are they labeled as intended?

is the combination of Category A and category B unique? or are there lots of duplicates?

The labels were initially switched, I’ve switched them back.

A and B are not unique

Firstly, looks like your Lower Bound and Upper Bound are switched? I'm going to treat the "Lower Bound" as the upper, since the bound is greater.
Instead of iterating over all 10M rows in your Value data, you could iterate over the rows in your Label data, which I hope is much smaller in your real problem, find all rows in the Value data that fit the interval at one time using DataFrame.loc, and then assign the label associated with that interval to all those rows at once.
Here I've created a 10M record DataFrame, and iterated over the row number of the label DF which is much smaller, and this code runs for me in <1s:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Category A':'Red Yellow Blue'.split(),
     'Category B':'One Two Three'.split(),
     'Upper Bound':[1,3,5],
     'Lower Bound':[3,5,7],
     'Label':'X Y Z'.split(),
     }
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['Value'] = np.random.uniform(1,7,10000000)

# Init the Label target column
df3['Label'] = None

# For each row in the Label DF, find rows in the Value DF that are in the interval
for i in range(len(df1)):

    #Then assign the Label for all of the rows you selected
    df3.loc[
        (df3['Value'] <= df1['Lower Bound'].values[i])&
        (df3['Value'] > df1['Upper Bound'].values[i]), 
        'Label'] = df1['Label'].values[i]

Here you have to trust your bounds in df1 are correctly non-overlapping, but this should do the trick.

Thank you - got me down to 38s from over an hour
